# Limit horizontal range of centered div when resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two divs. One should be positioned 5% from the left window border, the other should be to the right of the previously mentioned div and centred relative to window width. If the window is made too narrow it should not overlap the first div, and it should not move below either.

Whatever comes after should be positioned below the tallest of the first two divs.

How can I do this?

The closest I've come is to use a float for the first div. http://jsfiddle.net/7qVLm/

edit: Here's the final result that I'm happy with: http://jsfiddle.net/ATHpg/

Thanks to both @Christopher Smithson and @gmebeh whose answers helped me to get to this solution.

Comment: Should our solutions assume that the divs have variable amounts or fixed amounts of content?

Comment: Fixed amount of content.

Comment: for your last point: you can add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#container` to make it stretch to accomodate any encapsulated div - in other words ensure that any content after comes below the higher of the elements `#d1` and `#d2` (assuming you're not going to add a height to it).

Comment: Should the content within `#d1` and `#d2` be centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle to consider for your solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/f2Muj/5/

Answer (score 1):

With percentage-based `width`'s you can make this happen:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2Muj/7/)

- `#d1` is 5% from the left, center-aligned content
- `#d2` is centered relative to the browser window, and will never overlap `#d1`
- Both use fixed heights to accomodate fixed amounts of content

Play around with the percentages to get the exact width you you want.